# Session variable is not working properly how can i improve

Tags: php, session, variables, unset

```
$_SESSION['profile_updated']="yes";
```

Settingup session variable.!

```
<div class="col-md-12">
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['profile_updated'])){ ?>
<div class="confirmationmsgssg">Profile Updated successfully.</div> 
<?php unset($_SESSION['profile_updated']); } ?>
<h3>Your personal info</h3>
</div>
```

I am trying to show the alert message by using session..

Actually this is a enhancement project i can not change the whole code because it is there in a lot pages

What actually happening with the code is first it is check in the view page like if `$_SESSION['profile_updated']` is there show the message and it will automatically disappear after 3 second .. when i refresh the page that message should not appear because i have not updated anything for that i have to use unset..

> It is working fine if i remove `unset($_SESSION['profile_updated']);`
>   this unset. but when i add this I don't why it is not working

i have checked everywhere `session_start();` is in my first line of php
What could be the possible error..?
I have tried with `ob_start();` Didn't worked..!

Comment: `<div class="col-md-12">
<?php if(!empty($_SESSION['profile_updated'])){ ?>
<div class="confirmationmsgssg">Profile Updated successfully.</div> 
<?php $_SESSION['profile_updated'] = ''; } ?>
<h3>Your personal info</h3>
</div>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Clear the cookies and it has to work everything is right.**

```
<div class="col-md-12">
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['profile_updated'])){ ?>
<div class="confirmationmsgssg">Profile Updated successfully.</div>
<?php unset($_SESSION['profile_updated']); } ?>
<h3>Your personal info</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: what is the difference between your answer code and OP's question code?

Comment: Abdul Waheed  i didn't see any change in the accepted answer code

Comment: I have cleared the cookies and tried a new browser it wokred, @Anant

Comment: @AbdulWaheed  `I  have cleared the cookies and tried a new browser it wokred`:- what do you mean by new browser?

Comment: @AbdulWaheed  then what happen in fiirefox?Not working?

Answer (score 3):

Your code looks perfectly fine to me.I don't know why this not worked.

try once with `!empty` and `$_SESSION['profile_updated'] = ''`

```
<div class="col-md-12"> 
    <?php if(!empty($_SESSION['profile_updated'])){ ?> 
        <div class="confirmationmsgssg">Profile Updated successfully.</div> 
        <?php $_SESSION['profile_updated'] = '';?>
    <?php  } ?> 
    <h3>Your personal info</h3>
```

Note:-

make sure that `session_start();` is there on top of your file

***Try once with clearing cache and cookie and check with your original code.***